# How to fetch the disk difference before and after adding a new disk

Tags: ansible, vmware-vcenter, ansible-playbook, filtering, extend

I'm preparing a playbook to find the newly scanned HDD from vmware, I used below filtering to fetch the no. of HDDs:

```yaml
before_add: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | select('string') | list }}"
```

> OUTPUT- ['sr0', 'sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'dm-2', 'dm-3', 'dm-0', 'dm-1']

then add a new HDD using vmware_guest_disk module
and then I executed the setup module to fetch the latest no. of disks

```yaml
after_add: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | select('string') | list }}"
```

> OUTPUT: ['sr0', 'sda', 'sdb', 'sdc', 'sdd', 'dm-2', 'dm-3', 'dm-0', 'dm-1']

Since the managed host is remote node, I'm not able to think of lookup and difference filtering. Kindly suggest how to fetch the difference: "SDD"

Answer (score 0):

[Adding custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts) is what you're looking for. This serves the very purpose of storing persistent custom facts. For example, create the directory for the custom facts and display the variable *ansible_local*

```yaml
    - name: Create directory for ansible custom facts
      ansible.builtin.file:
        state: directory
        recurse: true
        path: /etc/ansible/facts.d
    - debug:
        var: ansible_local
```

The variable *ansible_local* shall be an empty dictionary if you haven't configured custom facts before

```yaml
  ansible_local: {}
```

Set the variables *before_add* and *after_add*, and display the difference

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        before_add: "{{ ansible_local.devices.general.before_add|
                        default([]) }}"
        after_add: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys()|
                       select('string')|list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ after_add|difference(before_add) }}"
```

When you run the play for the first time the variable *before_add* will be an empty list and the debug task should display all devices, e.g.

```yaml
  msg:
  - loop1
  - nvme0n1
    ...
```

Here comes the most important part of storing the persistent custom fact. For example, copy the dictionary into the file

```yaml
    - name: Install custom devices fact
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        content: |
          {"general": {"before_add": {{ after_add }} }}
        dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/devices.fact
```

When you run the play again *setup* should read *ansible_local*

```yaml
  ansible_local:
    devices:
      general:
        before_add:
        - loop1
        - nvme0n1
          ...
```

and there shall be no difference between *before_add* and *after_add*

```yaml
  msg: []
```

If you add a device the debug shall display the difference, e.g.

```yaml
  msg:
  - sda
```

But, the difference will be empty if you remove the device. If you want to see both added and removed devices use *symmetric_difference* instead of *difference*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ after_add|symmetric_difference(before_add) }}"
```